# ASP.NET report expression gives error

Tags: asp.net, .net, reportviewer

The following expression gives me error. I try to format time span as

```
hh:mm:ss
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont know. It just says error

Comment: Try to hover your mouse over the error and see the error message. Or pass 12345 in teh FromTicks and see if that works.

Comment: It shows nothing when i hover my mouse on the error. And passing 12345 gives the same error

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using an XML data source? In that case you might have a bit of trouble with dates.

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1480370.aspx?TimeSpan%20and%20ReportViewer):

For the Matrix :

```
=System.String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!duurHHMM.Value)).Hours,System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!duurHHMM.Value)).Minutes)
```

For the Chart :

```
=System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!duurHHMM.Value)).TotalMinutes
```